# How to drop several rows with specific values in columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with ' ?' instead of NaNs where are values are missing. How can I remove all rows where ' ?' do show up? To be more specific there are only three columns with question marks in them.

I actually managed to delete rows with question marks but only in one of the columns. Rows with QMs in different columns remained.

Comment: Try: `df.replace(' ?', np.NaN).dropna()`. Don't forget to `import numpy as np`

Comment: If the data frame is read using `read_csv`, you can use the `na_values` argument to specify the strings / values that should be treated as NaN.